# Check if someone send 2 same messages in 5 seconds with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Does anyone know how to check if someone is sending the same message two times in the same channel, in an interval of 5 seconds (there may be other messages from other people between the two messages) ?

(I'm new with Javascript and Discord.js)

If someone could help me, it would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you want to check if a user sends the same message two times? How much time can pass between one message and the other? Do they have to be in the same channel? Do they have to directly one after the other or simply in the same timespan? If you could add more detail and tell us what you had in mind and what have you already tried I'll be happy to help you :)

Comment: @FedericoGrandi I've updated the post :) I hope I've explained it better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`TextChannel.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages)

```
client.on('message', message => {
  // this function can check whether the content of the message you pass is the same as this message
  let filter = msg => {
    return msg.content.toLowerCase() == message.content.toLowerCase() && // check if the content is the same (sort of)
           msg.author == message.author; // check if the author is the same
  }

  message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
    maxMatches: 1, // you only need that to happen once
    time: 5 * 1000 // time is in milliseconds
  }).then(collected => {
    // this function will be called when a message matches you filter
  }).catch(console.error);
});
```

Comment: you missed comma after maxMatches: 1